# What if any are the limitations of UNIX shred to wipe NTFS Windows disks?

Tags: windows, unix, shred

Before I shred a NTFS disk with Ubuntu, can I count on shred to overwrite all data?  Perhaps there is a better question to ask: please feel free to add additional questions that serve to trigger discussion regarding shred limits on NTFS disks.

Answer (score 1):

`shred` was intended to overwrite files. I'm not convinced that you could make it actually overwrite every block of your disk.

What don't you use [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) instead? DBAN is free and is intended to overwrite the entire disk, regardless of file system.

If your disk is a SSD, you should know that it's difficult to securely delete all of the contents.. Here's an [older article](http://arstechnica.com/security/2011/03/ask-ars-how-can-i-safely-erase-the-data-from-my-ssd-drive/) that begins explaining why.

Oh and if you prefer to stick with Unix command line tools, `dd` could accomplish what you're looking for. Eg:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb
```

Comment: DBAN does not work with SSD, so almost useless now. 90% of drives are SSD now